# Identify a 2-pin male 16 mm (approx) threaded metal connector

Tags: connector

Can anybody help me identify the mating of this connector? I know it is MIL_C5015 and outside diameter is 15.7 mm. I need part number and manufacturerp.

[image: Connector to mate to]

Comment: What is the diameter and spacing (pitch) of the pins?

Comment: There are multiple 5015 configurations with two pins: 12S-3, 14S-9, 16S-4, etc.  The shell size should narrow it down but that doesn't look like a standard housing type.  It looks like there's something printed on the side of the housing, what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

A number of manufacturers make circular connectors like this. Since you mentioned `MIL_C5015` it's likely a military-spec (which crosses into aerospace as well). Well-known manufacturers for these include Amphenol, TE Connectivity, Cannon (not to be confused with Canon; now ITT Interconnect), Glenair, and others.

When you know the basic dimensions and a specification as you do, one of the ways to find the connector is to use a distributor/vendor such as Digikey, Mouser, Newark, etc. to search for the available options.

For example, on Digikey, I used [these selections](https://www.digikey.com/short/35drhqv5) to narrow things down:

- Connectors
- Circular Connectors
- Circular Connector Housings
- Type: For Male Pins
- Series: I selected everything that contained '5015'
- Number of positions: 2
- Orientation: N (your photo shows the polarizing key centered between the pins)
- Fastening Type: Threaded (because your image shows threads)

You'd have to decide whether you want a panel mount, free-hanging (on the end of another cable), what size the contacts are, what material, color, etc. from the remaining options. In addition, Digikey doesn't carry everything, so this search might help you narrow down options, and then go look at other vendors or manufacturers.

For example, I went to [Amphenol Aerospace](https://www.amphenol-aerospace.com), looked for MIL 5015 connectors, and found this page which has a [downloadable matrix catalog PDF](https://www.amphenol-aerospace.com/resources/literature/download/mil-dtl-5015-matrix-catalog) of their MIL-DTL-5015 series. There, you can determine (or rule out) a lot more options for this type of connector.